# jQuery, Bootstrap click to remove tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, jtmpl

I have built  some functionality to allow users to add and remove tabs. The 'add' functionality works how I want it to, there will only ever be 5 tabs visible, the rest will appear in a dropdown. **See the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/y6em370x/1/)**

I have a few problems when I add the 'remove' functionality. Tabs are being removed correctly, but now for the problems:

1. If I have added more than 6 tabs (12 for example) and I click the button to remove the currently selected tab (which works) the '.active' class is set on the first dropdown element making it un-clickable? I have tried the following:

   `$('.dropdown ul #tab6').parent().removeClass('active');`
2. I am also unsure how to have the number on the tabs update as I remove tabs. For example I have Device [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] and I remove Device/tab 9 how can I have the tabs still read in order ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12])?
3. Any opinions if point 2 is the correct way to handle this?

I am really stuck on this so any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

I have realised that the ID of the tabs doesn't matter as long as they are unique. I have updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/bt0q1xof/), it has a simple .each() added to update the text in the tab selection.

I still have the issue of the first dropdown being selected when I remove a tab from the dropdown, can anyone help with that?

Comment: 1) Remove device button functionality is correct.
2) You have to change the Device number after each deletion.

Comment: Yep agree, but changing the number after each removal only works if it is the last device that is removed: see this https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/qjnnuerd/

Comment: That is not what he meant. I think he tried to say. If you have [1 2 3 4] and you remove 3 you have to go through every element after 3 and decrement them in this case decrement 4 to 3. You can do it by keeping the index of the removed element and setting a for loop that will take effect for j>=i

Comment: ahh ok, I will give that a try and post back :-) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way. It should be what you're looking for.

HTML (slightly modified)

```
<script id="tabTemp" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <div class='tab-pane' id='tab${device}'>
        This is device number <span class="dev-nr"></span>
        <p>Random string (to see tabs difference): <b>${randomStr}</b></p>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove btnRmv">Remove device</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script id="navTemp" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <li class="li-tab-toggle">
        <a href="#tab${device}" class="tab-toggle" data-toggle="tab">
            Device <span class="dev-nr"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</script>
<script id="dropTemp" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
            More Devices <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="drop"></ul>
    </li>
</script>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd">Add device</a>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="li-tab-toggle active"><a class="tab-toggle" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Device 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Device 1 content</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var maxTabs = 4, index = 1;

$('#btnAdd').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    index++;
    $('.tab-toggle').length !== maxTabs || 
        $('#tabs').append($.tmpl(dropTemp))
        .find('#drop').append($('.li-tab-toggle:last').removeClass('active'));

    $.tmpl(navTemp, {"device" : index}).insertAfter('.li-tab-toggle:last');
    $.tmpl(tabTemp, {"device" : index}).appendTo('.tab-content');
    $('.li-tab-toggle:last a').tab('show');
    updateTabs();
});

$(document).on('click', '.btnRmv', function(e){
    var tabs = $('.li-tab-toggle').length,
        nav = $('.li-tab-toggle.active');

    nav.parent('#tabs').find('#drop li:first').insertBefore('#tabs .dropdown');
    tabs !== maxTabs+1 || $('#drop li').insertBefore('#tabs .dropdown').siblings('.dropdown').remove();

    $('a', nav.is('li:last') ? nav.prev() : nav.next()).tab('show');
    nav.add($('a', nav).attr('href')).remove();
    updateTabs();
});

function updateTabs(){
    for(var i=0; i < $('.tab-toggle').length; i++){
        $('.tab-toggle:eq('+i+') .dev-nr, .tab-pane:eq('+i+') .dev-nr').text(i+1);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ujy0j3ao/)

And a bit [beautified version](https://jsfiddle.net/0aL4L8td/)

Comment: You are a legend, this works really well. 'Edie Johnny' answer worked ok, but this one is the best. With 2 fully working examples.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem: You need to add the `data-toggle="tab"` to your first tab to make it clickable.

And to update the tabs when some is removed, you could use some eachs when the remove tab button is clicked:

```
// Set a controller to see when 'each' comes to the dropdown menu
var dropdown = false;
// For each #tabs li a...
$('#tabs li a').each(function(index){
    // Test if the 'a' has a dropdown-toggle class
    if($(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle')) {
        // It's in the dropdown, set the controller to true
        dropdown = true;
        return true;
    } else {
        // If the 'a' has not a dropdown-toggle class, just update
        // with index+1 (because index starts with 0)
        // Also check if the dropdown is false
        if(!dropdown) {
            $(this).attr('href','#tab'+(index + 1)).html('Device ' + (index+1));
        } else {
            // If dropdown is true, we just have to plus 'index'
            // because if not, dropdown menu will start with tab 7
            // instead of 6
            $(this).attr('href','#tab'+(index)).html('Tab ' + (index));
        }
    }
});
// Don't forget to update your 'nextTab' var
nextTab = 0;
$('#tabs li a').each(function(index) {
    nextTab = nextTab + 1;
});
// Update the tab-pane too.
$('.tab-content .tab-pane').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('id','tab' + (index+1)).html('This is device number ' + (index+1) + '<div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-remove" id="btnRmv">Remove device</a></div>');
});
```

I updated the remove button section too:

```
// REMOVE TAB TAB
if (nextTab < 6) {
    $('.nav-tabs li.active').remove();
} else if(nextTab > 6) {
    $('.nav-tabs li.active .dropdown-menu li.active').remove();
    // Check if there's tabs inside the dropdown, if not,
    // remove the dropdown.
    if(!$(".dropdown-menu").find("li").length) {
        $('.dropdown').remove();
    }
}
```

Here is the forked [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soto2L20/3/).